# (VBA) Function that compute a formula (Net Promoter Score) from a list of scores

Tags: vba, excel, function, excel-formula

I am currently trying to create a function that compute the Net Promotor Score from a list of score ranked between 0 and 10. You can compute the NPS with this formula (the formula I am trying to code) :

- the pourcentage of scores above 8 (so 8, 9, 10) - the pourcentage of scores below 6 (so 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 and 0)

So I created this code below (with Rng as the range of cells I will choose when writing my formula) which does not seem to work. I have defined every values and still, the #VALUE error appears. Could someone please explain me where my mistakes are ?

```
Function NPSCOMPUTE(Rng As Range)

Dim Cell As Range
Dim NPS As Integer
Dim PourcentagePromoters As Integer
Dim PourcentageDetractors As Integer
Dim Total As Integer
Dim Promoters As Integer
Dim Detractors As Integer

Range("D1").Value = "Net Promotor Score"
Detractors = 0
Promoters = 0

Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Rng)

For Each Cell In Rng
    If Cell.Value >= 8 Then
    Promoters = WorksheetFunction.Count(Cell.Value > 8)
    Promoters = Promoters + 1
    ElseIf Cell.Value <= 6 Then
    Detractors = WorksheetFunction.Count(Cell.Value < 6)
    Detractors = Detractors + 1
    End If
Next Cell

PourcentagePromoters = (Promoters * 100) / Total
PourcentageDetractors = (Detractors * 100) / Total
NPS = PourcentagePromoters - PourcentageDetractors

End Function
```

I hope someone will be able to help me out, thanks a lot !

Comment: Do you mean to do `NPSCOMPUTE = PourcentagePromoters - PourcentageDetractors`?  You never end up giving your `NPSCOMPUTE` function a value.

Comment: Right, thanks for your comment ! I have tried to edit my code but it still does not work, I have the same #VALUE issue ...

Comment: Not sure what you are intending with `Promoters = WorksheetFunction.Count(Cell.Value > 8)` COUNT does not allow criteria.  I think you need to get rid of both those lines.  Infact I think you can get rid of the loop entirely and use `Promoters =Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(rng,">=8")` and change to "<=6" for detractors.

Comment: My intention was to count the numbers of values above 8 in order to compute the pourcentage of promoters afterwards. Yet again, even when I get rid the loop I still have this VALUE issue ...

Comment: You cannot have the `Range("D1").Value = "Net Promotor Score"` line in a UDF called from the worksheet.

Comment: You might also want to review your definition of NPS. I believe the standard definition defines promoters as those answering only 9 or 10, not 8. See for instance http://www.npscalculator.com/en and https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/net-promoter-score-calculation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't correctly name the function return value `NPSCOMPUT`. But you could also simplify and avoid the loop which doesn't work as you expect.

This

```
Promoters = WorksheetFunction.Count(Cell.Value > 8)
```

Should be

```
Promoters = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, ">=" & 8)
```

And so on.

As spotted by @ScottCraner : you can't have a UDF alter another cell with the line

```
 Range("D1").Value = "Net Promotor Score"
```

This is listed along with other udf limitations here:

[Description of limitations of custom functions in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel)

Depending on whether blank rows can be present:

`Total = Rng.Cells.Count`  or `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, ">" & 0)`

```
Public Sub test()

With ActiveSheet

    MsgBox NPSCOMPUTE(.Range("A1:A10"))

End With


End Sub

Private Function NPSCOMPUTE(ByVal Rng As Range) As Double

Dim Cell As Range
Dim PourcentagePromoters As Double
Dim PourcentageDetractors As Double
Dim Total As Long
Dim Promoters As Long
Dim Detractors As Long

'Range("D1").Value = "Net Promotor Score"

Detractors = 0
Promoters = 0

Total = Rng.Cells.Count ' or Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, ">" & 0)
Promoters = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, ">=" & 8)
Detractors = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, "<=" & 6)

PourcentagePromoters = Promoters / Total
PourcentageDetractors = Detractors / Total

NPSCOMPUTE = 100 * (PourcentagePromoters - PourcentageDetractors)

End Function
```

Comment: detractors are not the difference as 7 is nuetral.

Comment: Oops. Thanks. I will amend.

Comment: And if this is being called from the worksheet the `Range("D1").Value = "Net Promotor Score"` will cause an issue.

Comment: I was assuming not. But yes you can't have a UDF alter another cell.

Comment: I think you were right regarding `Range("D1").Value = "Net Promotor Score"` line code ! I just have a question regarding the code you wrote : `(Rng, "<>" & 7)`. It asks excel to count the number of values in the range that are equal, superior and inferior to 7 ? Because the total is supposed to be the total amount of values (including 7) in the range.

Comment: Yes exactly ! Thanks a lot I wasn't actually aware I could do it without a loop !

Comment: @pnuts  absolutely! Guessing ARange is dynamic named range.